# How to use bootstrap css and javascript in selected pages in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, conflicting-libraries

I am in middle of developing an webapp using a MetroUI CSS. After developing a few pages I understood its css are conflicting with Bootstrap's css, so I removed the Bootstrap's css from the project.

Now in another page where I need to include a class from Bootstrap's css. How can I do that without conflicting the css with MetroUI css?

Comment: If your using less or sass (I would strongly advise you do) then you can just import the specific module you want instead of it all, hopefully reducing conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use both MetroUI and Bootstrap in your webapp.  Since these are two different libraries/frameworks trying to do a lot of the same stuff you are going to have conflicts and that is unfortunately unavoidable.

My recommendation would be to pick the one you plan on using the most and then overwriting any styles you'd like in your own custom style sheet.

For example:  You like most things about MetroUI but prefer how Bootstraps buttons look.  Well you can reference MetroUI and then pull out the bootstrap button styles you like and include them in a custom style sheet (making sure you overwrite any MetroUI styles you don't like).  Then reference your custom style sheet after MetroUI and it will overwrite MetroUI with the Bootstrap button styles you have included.